# How do you set the column width of a Scala Swing Table

Tags: swing, scala

In Java, you can set the preferred column width of a JTable using the getColumnModel method, but in scala swing you can't do that. So is there a way to set the column width of a Scala Swing Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most scala.swing components just "wrap" Java-Components. All Methods from the Java-Component can be accessed via the peer.

```
(new Table).peer.getColumnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0)
```

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know about the peer. Poor me. Anyways thanks. It now works